# Typescript React Tabs unable to reslove type errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to convert Reactjs Component to Typescript Component

Tabs Component is shown below

```js
<Tabs>
<Tab label="one"></Tab>
<Tab label="two"></Tab>
</Tabs>
```

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
const Tabs = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(children[0].props.label);
};
```

I get typescript error like `props` is not defined.

How can I declare interface to children property?

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-sound-znvgz5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Tabs Props like that:

```
interface TabsProps {
  children: React.ReactElement<TabProps>[]
};
```

Thats would "tell" typescript that children are elements that have `TabProps`, meaning they have label in their props that can be accessed.

Comment: What is diff between React.Component  and React.ReactElement?

Comment: When you have a functional react component, element is the object returned from the function. When you have a class react component, element is the object returned from the render() method.

So, while react element is the type of a single instance, react component is a reusable building block, with depth, complexity and a lifecycle.